# How do I make my javascript function change the color of my text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a website. And, on my website, on the menu page, I want my menu options to change color depending on which one has been clicked on. For example, when the page loads, it automatically starts on main, so the main button is green. But, when I click vegoption, I want vegoption to turn green and mainoption to turn black. And the same system for the other options.
Please forgive me if I have done things wrong in my javascript. I'm very new to the language. If there are any other improvements I can make, please let me know.

Here is the code:

```
/* Start Variables */

:root {
  --aa-color: #57C324;
}


/* End Variables */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}


/* Start Navbar */

.navbar-wrapper {
  // background: blue;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px 8px #888888;
  z-index: 100;
  position: relative;
}

.leftside {
  // background: green;
  width: 50%;
  height: 10px;
}

.rightside {
  width: 50%;
  // background: red;
}

.options {
  // background: yellow;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.linkhome {
  font-size: 120%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  margin-right: 0%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.linkmenu {
  font-size: 120%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--aa-color);
  ;
  margin-right: 0%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.linkabout {
  font-size: 120%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  margin-right: 0%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.linkfood {
  font-size: 120%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  margin-right: 0%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.linkculture {
  font-size: 120%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  margin-right: 0%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.linkmenu:hover {
  color: var(--aa-color);
}

.linkabout:hover {
  color: var(--aa-color);
}

.linkfood:hover {
  color: var(--aa-color);
}

.linkculture:hover {
  color: var(--aa-color);
}


/* End Navbar */


/* Start Main */

.injera-menu {
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  display: block;
}

.ourmenutext {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -25%;
  font-size: 400%;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#10CB00, #10CB00, #FFC701, #FF0101, #FF0101);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 3px white;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 3px black;
  margin-left: 3%;
}

.menuoptions {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.mainoption {
  margin: 2% 5%;
  color: var(--aa-color);
}

.vegoption {
  margin: 2% 5%;
}

.specialoption {
  margin: 2% 5%;
}

.drinksoption {
  margin: 2% 5%;
}

.vegoption:hover {
  color: var(--aa-color)
}

.specialoption:hover {
  color: var(--aa-color)
}

.drinksoption:hover {
  color: var(--aa-color)
}


/* Start Menu */

.menu {
  position: relative;
}


/* Start Main Menu */

.menumain {
  justify-content: center;
  color: var(--aa-color);
  dis
}

.price {
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid var(--aa-color);
  padding: 1% 2%;

}

.dishtitle {
  margin-left: 40%;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.dishinfo {
  padding: 5% 10%;
  font-size: 150%;
}

.menu-item {
  width: 70%;
  border: 3px solid var(--aa-color);
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px 8px #888888;
    justify-content: center;
}

.menuveg {
    width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  color: var(--aa-color);
  display: none;
}

.one-pers, .two-pers, .three-pers, .four-pers{
     margin: 4% 40%;
   display: flex;
}

.perstext{
  width: 50%;
  margin-right: 20%;
}

.persprice{
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.menuspecial {
    width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  color: var(--aa-color);
  display: none;
}

.dishinfo2 {
  padding: 5% 10%;
  font-size: 150%;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
/* End Menu */


/* End Main */
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Addis Abeba | Menu</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/menu.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Start Navbar -->
  <nav>
    <div class="navbar-wrapper">
      <div class="leftside">

      </div>
      <div class="rightside">
        <div class="options">
          <a href="#" class="linkhome">Home</a>
          <a href="menu.html" class="linkmenu">Menu</a>
          <a href="#" class="linkabout">About Us</a>
          <a href="#" class="linkfood">Our Food</a>
          <a href="#" class="linkculture">Ethiopian Culture</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- End Navbar -->

  <!-- Start Main -->
  <div class="our-menu">
    <div class="ourmenusection">
      <div class="img1">
        <img src="img/injera.png" alt="injera" class="injera-menu">
      </div>
      <div class="text-ourmenu">
        <h1 class="ourmenutext">

          Menu</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="menuoptions">
    <h2 class="mainoption">Main</h2>
    <h2 class="vegoption" onclick="showveg()">Vegetarian</h2>
    <h2 class="specialoption" onclick="showspecial()">Special</h2>
    <h2 class="drinksoption" onclick="showspecial()">Drinks</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="menu">

    <!-- Start Main Menu -->
    <div class="menumain">
      <div class="menu-item">
        <div class="price">
          <p>CHF 21.-</p>
        </div>
        <div class="dishtitle">
          <h1>Key Wat</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="dishinfo">
          Tender morsels of meat prepared in specially spiced butter, seasoned with onions and green peppers, sprinkled with garlic and ginger.
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="menu-item">
        <div class="price">
          <p>CHF 23.-</p>
        </div>
        <div class="dishtitle">
          <h1>Doro Wat</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="dishinfo">
          Chicken cooked in specially seasoned red sauce and Ethiopian butter.
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="menu-item">
        <div class="price">
          <p>CHF 23.-</p>
        </div>
        <div class="dishtitle">
          <h1>Yebeg Wat</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="dishinfo">
          Morsels of lamb prepared in special herb butter, seasoned with onions and green peppers and sprinkled with garlic and ginger.
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="menu-item">
        <div class="price">
          <p>CHF 25.-</p>
        </div>
        <div class="dishtitle">
          <h1>Kitfo</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="dishinfo">
          Steak tartare, Ethiopian style, seasoned with special hot red pepper and spiced butter
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="menu-item">
        <div class="price">
          <p>CHF 24.-</p>
        </div>
        <div class="dishtitle">
          <h1>Beef Tibs</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="dishinfo">
          Strips of beef sauteed with onion and pepper.
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="menu-item">
        <div class="price">
          <p>CHF 24.-</p>
        </div>
        <div class="dishtitle">
          <h1>Lamb Tibs</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="dishinfo">
          Cubes of lamb fried in buter, onions, green and black peppers.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Start Vegetarian Menu -->

    <div class="menuveg">
      <div class="menu-item">
        <div class="price">
          <p>CHF 17.-</p>
        </div>
        <div class="dishtitle">
          <h1>Shiro</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="dishinfo">
          Yellow split peas cooked in special sauce and blended into a puree flavored with spices.
                </div>
            </div>

      <div class="menu-item">
        <div class="price">
          <p>CHF 17.-</p>
        </div>
        <div class="dishtitle">
          <h1>Misir</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="dishinfo">
          Cracked lentil cooked in spiced sauce.
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="menu-item">
        <div class="price">
          <p>CHF 16.-</p>
        </div>
        <div class="dishtitle">
          <h1>Gomen</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="dishinfo">
          Assortment  of spicy chopped vegetables cooked in spiced butter, onions and various kinds of exotic peppers.
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="menu-item">
        <div class="dishtitle" style="margin-left: 30%;">
          <h1>Vegetarian Tasting Menu</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="pers">
            <div class="one-pers">
                <div class="perstext">
                    <h3>1 Pers</h3>
                </div>
                        <div class="persprice">
                            <div class="price">
                      <p>CHF 22.-</p>
                    </div>
                        </div>
            </div>

                    <div class="two-pers">
                <div class="perstext">
                    <h3>2 Pers</h3>
                </div>
                        <div class="persprice">
                            <div class="price">
                      <p>CHF 44.-</p>
                    </div>
                        </div>
            </div>

                    <div class="three-pers">
                <div class="perstext">
                    <h3>3 Pers</h3>
                </div>
                        <div class="persprice">
                            <div class="price">
                      <p>CHF 66.-</p>
                    </div>
                        </div>
            </div>

                    <div class="four-pers">
                <div class="perstext">
                    <h3>4 Pers</h3>
                </div>
                        <div class="persprice">
                            <div class="price">
                      <p>CHF 88.-</p>
                    </div>
                        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Start Special Menu -->

    <div class="menuspecial">
      <div class="menu-item">
        <div class="dishtitle">
          <h1>Addis Abeba Special</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="dishinfo2">
          <h3>Includes:</h3>
          Tibs, Yebuegue Alicha, Doro Woot and choice of Lentils or Vegetables
        </div>
        <div class="pers">
                    <div class="two-pers">
                <div class="perstext">
                    <h3>2 Pers</h3>
                </div>
                        <div class="persprice">
                            <div class="price">
                      <p>CHF 52.-</p>
                    </div>
                        </div>
            </div>

                    <div class="three-pers">
                <div class="perstext">
                    <h3>3 Pers</h3>
                </div>
                        <div class="persprice">
                            <div class="price">
                      <p>CHF 78.-</p>
                    </div>
                        </div>
            </div>

                    <div class="four-pers">
                <div class="perstext">
                    <h3>4 Pers</h3>
                </div>
                        <div class="persprice">
                            <div class="price">
                      <p>CHF 99.-</p>
                    </div>
                        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="menu-item">
        <div class="dishtitle">
          <h1>Tasting Menu</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="dishinfo2">
          <h3>Includes:</h3>
          Tibs, Yebuegue Alicha, Doro Woot, Kitfo and choice of Lentils or Vegetables
        </div>
        <div class="pers">
                    <div class="two-pers">
                <div class="perstext">
                    <h3>2 Pers</h3>
                </div>
                        <div class="persprice">
                            <div class="price">
                      <p>CHF 60.-</p>
                    </div>
                        </div>
            </div>

                    <div class="three-pers">
                <div class="perstext">
                    <h3>3 Pers</h3>
                </div>
                        <div class="persprice">
                            <div class="price">
                      <p>CHF 90.-</p>
                    </div>
                        </div>
            </div>

                    <div class="four-pers">
                <div class="perstext">
                    <h3>4 Pers</h3>
                </div>
                        <div class="persprice">
                            <div class="price">
                      <p>CHF 115.-</p>
                    </div>
                        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- End Main -->
    <!-- Start JS -->

    <script type="text/javascript">

   function showmain() {
     document.getElementsByClassName("menumain")[0].style.display = "inline-block";
     document.getElementsByClassName("menuveg")[0].style.display = "none";
     document.getElementsByClassName("menuspecial")[0].style.display = "none";
     document.getElementsByClassName("menudrinks")[0].style.display = "none";
     document.getElementsByClassName("mainoption")[0].style.color = "#57C324";
     document.getElementsByClassName("vegoption")[0].style.color = "black";
     document.getElementsByClassName("specialoption")[0].style.color = "black";
     document.getElementsByClassName("drinksoption")[0].style.color = "black";
   }

     function showveg() {
         document.getElementsByClassName("menumain")[0].style.display = "none";
         document.getElementsByClassName("menuveg")[0].style.display = "inline-block";
       document.getElementsByClassName("menuspecial")[0].style.display = "none";
       document.getElementsByClassName("menudrinks")[0].style.display = "none";
       document.getElementsByClassName("mainoption")[0].style.color = "black";
       document.getElementsByClassName("vegoption")[0].style.color = "#57C324";
       document.getElementsByClassName("specialoption")[0].style.color = "black";
       document.getElementsByClassName("drinksoption")[0].style.color = "black";
   }

   function showspecial() {
      document.getElementsByClassName("menumain")[0].style.display = "none";
      document.getElementsByClassName("menuveg")[0].style.display = "none";
      document.getElementsByClassName("menuspecial")[0].style.display = "inline-block";
      document.getElementsByClassName("menudrinks")[0].style.display = "none";
      document.getElementsByClassName("mainoption")[0].style.color = "black";
      document.getElementsByClassName("vegoption")[0].style.color = "black";
      document.getElementsByClassName("specialoption")[0].style.color = "#57C324";
      document.getElementsByClassName("drinksoption")[0].style.color = "black";
    }

   function showdrinks() {
      document.getElementsByClassName("menumain")[0].style.display = "none";
      document.getElementsByClassName("menuveg")[0].style.display = "none";
      document.getElementsByClassName("menuspecial")[0].style.display = "none";
      document.getElementsByClassName("menudrinks")[0].style.display = "inline-block";
      document.getElementsByClassName("mainoption")[0].style.color = "black";
      document.getElementsByClassName("vegoption")[0].style.color = "black";
      document.getElementsByClassName("specialoption")[0].style.color = "black";
      document.getElementsByClassName("drinksoption")[0].style.color = "#57C324";

    }
    </script>

    <!-- End JS -->
</body>

</html>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: In your `:hover` definitions put a color hexcode, not a reference to `--aa-color`

Comment: im not sure if you are accepting jquery answers, but i did a bit of rewriting of the code: https://jsfiddle.net/vwekud8a/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you aren't using a framework, I'd still suggest using jQuery, especially because it's very beginner friendly in my opinion.

The latest version of jQuery can be found [here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery).
You can simply link it within your html like this:

```
<head>    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
```

With jQuery, you can set events for when a object is clicked.
An example for a click event for one of your classes would be something like this:

```
$(".vegoption").click(function(){
    // do something when .vegoption is clicked
})
```

If you want to change its color when clicked, you can simply call .css() to change the background-color like this:

```
$(".vegoption").click(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "green");
})
```

If you want a certain class to be colored green when landing on the page, you can call the `$(document).ready()` event which is included with jQuery and calls everything within its function as soon as the page has loaded correctly.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".mainoption").css("background-color", "green");
})
```

In order make sure that only one option is green at once, you can simply change the color of all the other options back to their defaults within these events as well just like explained in the examples above.

Comment: @SiannaZewdie You're welcome, glad to help a fellow Swiss friend :)